# Should I use "everyone's", "everyones'" or "everyones"?

Tags: word-choice, possessives

I have the following sentence:

> Joe got everyone's attention and started to speak.

Should it be *everyone's*, *everyones'* or *everyones*?

Comment: Good question. This is not answerable using Wiktionary (they don't have those words).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As [Robusto says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/should-i-use-everyones-everyones-or-everyones/6059#6059), you should use *everyone’s*.  Neither *everyones’* nor *everyones* is a word.

Note that *everyone* is always singular and cannot be pluralized, which means *everyones* is incorrect.  If *everyones* were a word, *everyones’* would be the possessive form of *everyones*, but since *everyones* is incorrect, *everyones’* is also incorrect.

Comment: +1 for **since everyones is incorrect everyones' is also incorrect**

Comment: Thank you  could you add what the `‘s` stands for? Is it `is` or `us`(Like `let’s` is for `let us`)? And how to make sense out of it? Saying both `Joe got everyone is attention` or `Joe got everyone us attention` don’t make much sense to me.

Comment: @CodingEdgar It's a _possessive_ "s", as in "Fred's house", "Joe's dog" - it indicates 'belonging to'.

Comment: I'm happy with this answer but why, Why?!, and perhaps who, decided everyones is not a valid word?

Answer (score 15):

It should be *everyone's*.