# How to form the possessive case of indefinite pronouns?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, indefinite-pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use “everyone's”, “everyones'” or “everyones”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/should-i-use-everyones-everyones-or-everyones)

I was writing a sentence in Google Docs that contained the following fragment:

> ...is in everyone's best interest...

The word "everyone's" was flagged as a spelling error and the suggested replacement was "every one's."

Which form is correct?

Comment: It would seem like "everyone´s" is correct.

There is a related question here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/should-i-use-everyones-everyones-or-everyones       edit: But maybe I did not understand your question.

Comment: Was it flagged as a spelling error, or an error in grammar?

Comment: @pavium: It was underlined with red, so I'm assuming it was spelling.

Comment: @Mendel: Well spotted. Voting to close on the grounds your link covers this question.

Comment: Presumably, Microsoft speller thinks that you can add 's for the possessive in nouns, but not pronouns, and classifies *everyone* as a pronoun.

Answer (score 3):

The possessive of *everyone* is *everyone's*, in the same way the possessive of *everybody* is *everybody's*.

In my experience, the spelling checkers get confused by contractions. The one that runs on the Mac OS X has problems when I write, for example, *it's Sunday* and it suggests me to use *its* if I meant to use the possessive; the previously used message was suggesting something different, showing that the spelling checker had doubts about what I meant with *it's*, even in a phrase similar to "it's a cat."

Answer (score 2):

*Everyone* is a singular pronoun, and the way to morph a singular regular noun/pronoun (not ending in 's') into its possessive form is to append *'s* to it.  *Everyone* is not an exception, therefore *everyone's* is the correct possessive.